# Problem with divergence of random variable with Bernoulli distribution

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Let's define
$$P(X_n)=\begin{cases}1,&w.p=\; \frac1n \\0,&w.p = 1-\frac1n\end{cases}$$
**I want to show that $(X_n)\rightarrow0$ i.p converge.**

$(X_n\rightarrow X) \Leftrightarrow \forall_{\varepsilon>0} \;\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(|X_n-X|)\le \varepsilon.$

$P(|X_n-X|)\le \varepsilon \rightarrow 1 \Rightarrow P(X_n\le \varepsilon) \rightarrow 1$.

So it will be truth if $(X_n)$ has finite number of ones. And I don't know what to do next. Can you please give me some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $\varepsilon \geq 1$, $P(|X_n|>\varepsilon)=0$ since $|X_n|\leq 1$ with probability one and for $0<\varepsilon <1$
$$
P(|X_n|>\varepsilon)=P(X_n=1)=\frac{1}{n}\to 0
$$
as $n\to \infty$.